# Joining Tables Based on Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a table that has a lot of fields that are foreign keys referencing a related table. I am writing a script in PHP that will do the db queries. When I query this table for its data I need to know the values associated with these keys not the key.

How do most people go about this?

A 101 way to do this would be to query this table for its data including the foreign keys and then query the related tables to get each key's value. This could be a lot of queries (~10).

**Question 1:** I think I could write 1 query with a bunch of joins. Would that be better?

This approach also requires the querying script to know which table fields are foreign keys. Since I have many tables like this but all with different fields, this means writing nice generic functions is hard. MySQL InnoDB tables allow for foreign constraints. I know the database has these set up correctly.

**Question 2:** What about the idea of querying the table and identifying what the constraints are and then matching them up using whatever process I decide on from Question 1. I like this idea but never see it being used in code. Makes me think its not a good idea for some reason. I would use something like SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; to find what constraints/relationships exist for that table.

Thank you for any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You talk about writing "nice generic functions", but I think you are thinking a little TOO generic here.

Personally I would just write a query with a bunch of joins in it.  If you want to abstract all that join logic away and not have to worry about it, then you should probably look at using an ORM instead of writing the SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

At some level, the system should run queries using joins, whether those queries are written explicitly by the application programmer or generated automatically by the [data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer). Option 1 is definititely better than the naive option. As for some other query creation options (by no means an exhaustive list):

- You could abstract out all database operations, much as PDO abstracts out connecting and query operations (i.e. preparing & executing queries). Use this to get table metadata, including foreign keys, which could then be used to construct queries automatically.
- You could write object specifications in some other format (e.g. XML) and a class that would  use that to both generate PHP classes and database tables. You find this more in Enterprise applications than smaller projects. This option has more overhead than others, and thus isn't suitable if you only have a few classes to model. Occurrences of this option might also be a consequence of [Conway's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Law), which I first heard as Richard Fairly's variant: "The structure of a system reflects the structure of the organization that built it."
- You could take a [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594)-like approach. In PHP, this would mean writing numerous functions or methods that the application programmer can chain together which would create a query. The application programmers are ultimately responsible for joining tables, though they never write a `JOIN` themselves.

Rather than thinking about how to create the queries, a better problem approach is to think about how to interface the DB and the application. This leads to [patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400052) such as [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160409/joining-tables-based-on-foreign-keys) that fall into the category of [Object-Relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) ([ORM](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2009/08/10-orm-patterns-components-of-object.html)). Note that some patterns (such as AR), other ORM techniques and even [ORM itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) have issues of their own. Any of the above query creation options can be used in the implementation of a data access pattern.

The problem with using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is it doesn't work with most (all?) other RDBMSs. If you want to marry your app to MySQL, go ahead, but the decision could haunt you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of record counts are you working with, both in the main data table(s) and the lookup tables?

As a general rule, you should join the lookup tables to the main table. If you have an excessive amount of joins and there aren't many UDFs involved here, there's a pretty good chance the table should be normalized a bit more. If the normalization is fine and the main data table is really wide, you could still split the table to multiple tables with 1:1 relationships so as to separate the frequently accessed columns from the infrequently accessed columns.

MySQL includes support for the ANSI catalog INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS. You could use that to gather information on the FK relationships that exist.

Also, if there are combinations of joins you use frequently, create a views or stored procedures based on those common operations.